# DynamoDB wants number if gets string and string if gets number

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb

`dynamodb` is being very indecisive for me. I have a random id generator that includes both letters and numbers, but when I use `putItem` an error appears saying: `ValidationException: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: random3string8of5letters4and2numbers`. 
If I give in and decide to make my id generator number only, it appears with another error: `ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key user_id expected: S actual: N` if I put `user_id: "999999"` 
I am very confused right now. Any help would help :)

Function where weird stuff is happening:

```js
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB();

async function addUser(username, password, email, firstName) {
    const items = {
        "user_id": {
            "N": 2 //or "2" or "j38873kjhad8123" or something like that
                   //normally r() - the random id generator that returns a random id
        },
        "username": {
            "S": username
        },
        "password": {
            "S": password
        },
        "email": {
            "S": email
        },
        "firstName": {
            "S": firstName
        }
    };


    const message = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        dynamo.putItem({
            TableName: 'user_data',
            Item: items 
        }, 
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) rej(err);
            else res({ id: user_id, message: `User added to database with user_id ${user_id}` });
        });
    });
    return message;
}
//example usage of function:
addUser("test", "test", "test", "test").then(...);
```

random id generator:

```js
function r() { //get randomized string 30 chars long
    let res = '';
    const chars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        res += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    return res;
}
```

[image: user_id type]

Comment: Your user_id is not a number so store it as a string e.g. `{ "S": "random3string8of5letters4and2numbers" }`

Comment: @jarmod the random id generator function returns a string, but it still appears with an error

Comment: @jarmod i've updated the post with the id generator function

Comment: Presumably user_id is a primary key attribute with type string in your table's definition. What problem do you have when indicating `"user_id" : { "S": "random3string8of5letters4and2numbers" }` in your item when calling putItem?

Comment: BTW no need to promisify AWS SDK calls. Simply use: `await dynamo.putItem(params).promise()`

Comment: When I indicate that, it gives me ``ValidationException: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: random3string8of5letters4and2numbers``. I'm taking this as "``random3string8of5letters4and2numbers`` is not a number", but this is confusing because I explicitly set ``user_id`` to be a string.

Comment: I will also keep that in mind :)

Comment: What type is user_id in your table's attribute definitions? It should be "S" for string, not "N" for number.

Comment: I've included a picture in the post.

Comment: Just to be clear: your item should have `"user_id" : { "S": r() }`. Is that what you have, or does your code have `"user_id" : { "N": r() }`?

Comment: @jarmod Oh... that's what did it! Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places that you need to indicate that `user_id` is a string:

1. in the attribute definitions when [creating your table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.CreateTable.html)
2. in the item you are passing to the [putItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) call

It looks like your table definition was correctly configured with `user_id` as a string so the problem must be in the parameters to your putItem call. Use the following:

```
"user_id" : { "S": r() }
```